# C programming error when building and running

Tags: scanf, building

Im following a youtube tutorial by Bucky in C programming. Every time i use scanf and enter the input i get an error pop up. i typed these exact same codes from the video tutorial but mine does not work.

HERE'S THE CODE:

```
int main()
{
int age;

printf("How old are you?\n");
scanf("%d, &age");

if (age>= 18){
printf("You may enter this website!");
}
if(age<18){
printf("nothing to see here!");
}
return 0;
}
```

It only works after compiling and running. But after i input the age, an error window pops up and says "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

I'm sure the codes are correct but What is causing this? Help me please so i can move forward.

Comment: *I'm sure the codes are correct*. Are you? Why? The code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You placed quote in incorrect place in `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d, &age");
```

should be:

```
scanf("%d", &age);
```

C language is limited in a ways to implement functions with variable numbers of arguments (which `scanf` is, since it's can read variable number of variables from terminal), so this is why such errors are possible.

Modern compilers will warn you about incorrect `scanf` usage, e.g. GCC will give a warning:

```
1.c: In function ‘main’:
1.c:8:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int *’ argument [-Wformat=]
 scanf("%d, &age");
 ^
```

By the way, your example misses

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: wow you're right and it worked!! i think i need some sleep. thanks a lot, i would upvote you but it wont let  me. thanks again